# bootstrap form styling with elements left and right

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

[image: FORM STYLE]

Okay. I'm trying to recreate this form in particular using as much default bootstrap styling as possible.

The problem I'm having is having the left and right sidelooking like this.

I'm using a Modal class for the dark background.

```
<div class="panel-footer modal_custom">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Talk to us</h2>
        <h4>What's on your mind?</h4>
        <form action="" role="form">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="form-elem-1"> Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="form-elem-1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="form-elem-2"> Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" id="form-elem-2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your telephone number" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="form-elem-3"> Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="form-elem-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your e-mail" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="form-elem-4"> Company</label>
                <input type="text" id="form-elem-4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your company name" />
            </div><br />
            <div class="form-group>
                <label for="form-elem-4"> Enquiry</label>
                <input type="text" id="form-elem-4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your enquiry" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't need much help on the color and those smaller things. just on how to position the Enquiry to the right and making it looks as close to the example as possible.

There isn't any css yet that affects much of the code above. And I'm failry new to the fomr function. How would I have the form actually work too.

Comment: You can check this [registration form tutorial](http://www.antonoffplus.com/how-to-create-a-registration-form-using-php-and-mysql/), and go through it and build a form by yourself. PS You need to put some effort before posting a question here. You could at least google: How to create a form using php.

Comment: @Tibbers I have almost no knowledge on how php forms work though. i Looked through it and tried it out, but i still Can't seem to make it work. but thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need, now you have add some your styles for button, and background

```
<div class="panel-footer modal_custom">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Talk to us</h2>
    <h4>What's on your mind?</h4>
    <form action="" role="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-elem-1"> Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="form-elem-1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-elem-2"> Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" id="form-elem-2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your telephone number" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-elem-3"> Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="form-elem-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your e-mail" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-elem-4"> Company</label>
            <input type="text" id="form-elem-4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your company name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3" for="comment">Comment:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="13" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>    
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9098/

Comment: This helped a lot thanks. changed a couple of things to allow for the styling to be as close to the design as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-build that form using responsive Table. Set the table with two columns and get the required design without change in CSS.